# Why does my if else condition not work in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a condition to some jquery script but for some reason I can't get it to work. I hope someone can tell me what I have got wrong.
I want the script to show different text in a div depending on the value of a variable gotten through ajax. Many thanks.

The ajax bit of my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       //Fetch data from server

       $.ajax({
           url: 'my_data.php',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {

               $("#a").text(data.a);
               $("#b").text(data.b);

               var a = data.a;
               var b = data.b;


               //Condition
               if (a > b) {
                   $("#advice").text("a is greater than b");
               } else {
                   $("#advice").text("b is greater a.");
               }
           }

       });
```

Comment: try to `alert(a+'  >  '+b)` before condition statement and what is the result ?

Comment: @martiendt that would simply alert a concatenated string. Don't see how that would help

Comment: I get the alert with the variable values regardless of whether 'a' is greater than 'b' or 'b' greater than 'a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try parsing your variable to integer using `parseInt(a)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //Fetch data from server

   $.ajax({
       url: 'my_data.php',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {

           $("#a").text(data.a);
           $("#b").text(data.b);

           var a = parseInt(data.a, 10);
           var b = parseInt(data.b, 10);


           //Condition
           if (a > b) {
               $("#advice").text("a is greater than b");
           } else {
               $("#advice").text("b is greater a.");
           }
       }

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data types of data.a and data.b you might get unexpected behaviour if they're not of the type *number*.

If data.a and data.b are strings, arrays or Object types, using [relational operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) will result in behaviour that might not be expected, for example:

```
console.log('19' > '109'); // false
console.log([1,2] > [2,3,4]); // false
console.log({} > {1: 2}); // false
```

You can convert strings to float using `parseFloat(data.a)` or int using `parseInt(data.a, 10)`. The 10 is the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Relational_operators).

To see what the types are of data.a and data.b are use the `typeof` keyword:

```
console.log(typeof data.a);
console.log(typeof data.b);
```

If these aren't Number, then convert them to float or int before using relational operators.

Comment: Thanks for this. They are numbers, I should have said.